# Parralax Scrolling: Chrome only issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a parralax scrolling CSS implementation which works perfectly well for Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome.

The style to achieve parralax scrolling:

```
#somediv {
  background: url(../assets/img/someImage.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

This style is being applied to a  el.

Strangely, when I refresh the page at a section where the fixed background image should be, it appears, only for that particular section. When I start scrolling to see where I have set the other fixed backgrounds, they don't show until I refresh.

I've noticed users having performance issues with their parralax scrolling on Chrome but I'm not at that stage, just need it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) preferably in a snippet.

Comment: Problem Solved. Turns out, I had been adding a background to my <body>    and a position:fixed which was messing up my layout of any following backgrounds.